# Let $X, Y$ be independent randoLet$U, V$ be independent of $X,Y$ .Show that $Z=\frac{(UX+VY)}{(U^2+V^2)^{\frac12}} \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

> Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables $N (0, 1)$ . Let $U, V$ be independent of $X, Y$ .Show that  $Z = \frac{(UX + VY)}{(U^2 + V^2)^{\frac 12}} \sim N (0, 1)$

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the characteristic function :
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[e^{itZ}] &= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{it\frac{UX+VY}{\sqrt{U^2+V^2}}}\middle|U,V\right]\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[e^{it\frac{U}{\sqrt{U^2+V^2}}X}\middle|U,V\right]\mathbb E\left[e^{it\frac{V}{\sqrt{U^2+V^2}}Y}\middle|U,V\right]\right]\\
&= \mathbb E\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2\left(\frac{U}{\sqrt{U^2+V^2}}\right)^2}e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2\left(\frac{V}{\sqrt{U^2+V^2}}\right)^2}\right]\\
&= e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}
\end{align*}
Using the conditional characteristic function.

Comment: I never studied the characteristic function but I have as exercise, I think I should use some other way to do it..

Comment: @P.Quinton why did you come up with $(U/\sqrt{U^2+V^2})^2 $ ? I mean, how did you get the square (which allow you to simplify indeed) ?

Comment: @AkaiM The characteristic function of $X$ is $\mathbb E[e^{iaX}] = e^{-a^2/2}$, if you replace $a$ by $t\frac{U}{\sqrt{U^2+V^2}}$, you get $t^2 \frac{U^2}{U^2+V^2}$.